# Interface with multiple implementations in OCaml

Tags: interface, module, ocaml

What is the conventional way to create an interface in OCaml? It's possible to have an interface with a single implementation by creating an interface file `foo.mli` and an implementation file `foo.ml`, but how can you create multiple implementations for the same interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to have multiple implementations for the same signature, define your signature inside a compilation unit, rather than as a compilation unit, and (if needed) similarly for the modules. There's an example of that in the standard library: the `OrderedType` signature, that describes modules with a type and a comparison function on that type:

```
module type OrderedType = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end
```

This signature is defined in both `set.mli` and `map.mli` (you can refer to it as either `Set.OrderedType` or `Map.OrderedType`, or even write it out yourself: signatures are structural). There are several compilation units in the standard library that have this signature (`String`, `Nativeint`, etc.). You can also define your own module, and you don't need to do anything special when defining the module: as long as it has a type called `t` and a value called `compare` of type `t -> t -> int`, the module has that signature. There's a slightly elaborate example of that in the standard library: the `Set.Make` functor builds a module which has the signature `OrderedType`, so you can build sets of sets that way.

```
(* All four modules passed as arguments to Set.Make have the signature Set.OrderedType *)
module IntSet = Set.Make(module type t = int val compare = Pervasives.compare end)
module StringSet = Set.Make(String)
module StringSetSet = Set.Make(StringSet)
module IntSetSet = Set.Make(IntSet)
```

Answer (score 10):

You must use modules and signatures. A `.ml` file implicitly define a module, and a `.mli` its signature. With explicit modules and signature, you can apply a signature to several different modules.

See [this chapter](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/index.html#chap-modules) of the online book "Developing Applications with OCaml".